# Почему обрывается соединение по websocket через 100 секунд?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, websocket

Имеется сайт с веб-сервером nginx. Также поднят вебсокет сервер. Nginx выступает в качестве прокси для сервера вебсокетов. В браузере устанавливается соединение по вебсокету. Проблема в том, что если по вебсокету не передаются данные на протяжении 100 секунд, то соединение обрывается.

Нагуглил что в конфиге nginx на это может влиять параметр proxy_read_timeout. Выставил 950 секунд и всё-равно по истечении 100 секунд соединение обрывается. Эксперимента ради параметр proxy_read_timeout выставил в 60 - произошел обрыв через эти 60 секунд, а вот при 950 секундах обрывает через 100 секунд.

Может не в настройке nginx дело, а в настройках самого вебсокета?

Также сайт подключен к Cloudeflare, но гугл говорит что Cloudeflare нормально работает с вебсокетами и не рубит соединение.

Конфиг nginx для вебсокет сервера:

```
upstream binaryt {
       server 127.0.0.1:9009;
}
```

location:

```
location /binaryt {
        proxy_pass http://binaryt;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout 950s;
        proxy_send_timeout 950s;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

Подключаюсь с помощью библиотеки binary js:

```
const Websocket = function () {
    this.client = new BinaryClient('wss://mydomain.com/binaryt');
}
```

После обрыва в обработчике close на сервере возвращается code = 1000, а на клиенте code = 1006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо предавать данные пeриодически -- пинг/понг.

Иначе невозможно узнать, жива ли другая сторона.

Если клиент не получает ничего от сервера пол минуты, то неизвестно:

- просто данных нет
- или соединение порвалось

Ведь websocket нужен для моментального оповещения, а не "моментального оповещения если повезет"

Comment: Да, действительно правильное решение - отправка ping-pong. Спасибо!